# How to determine which parameters are required when using substrate.query() to query a storage_function from polkascan's py-substrate-interface?

Tags: python, substrate, polkadot

When querying storage functions using [Polkascan's py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#storage-queries) how do you figure out which parameters are required?

For example, I am trying to discern how much KSM is on Karura via storage functions in the tokens (ORML) pallet.

See below code for example. I tried to `substrate.query()` [Tokens.TotalIssuance storage_function](https://karura.subscan.io/runtime/Tokens?version=2023#:%7E:text=Type-,TotalIssuance,-%7B%20%22origin%22%3A%20%22Map%22%2C%20%22n_map_type) but it requires 6 parameters:

```
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface

substrate = SubstrateInterface(url="wss://karura-rpc-0.aca-api.network/") 

result = substrate.query(module='Tokens',storage_function='TotalIssuance')
        
**ValueError**: Storage function requires 6 parameters, 0 given
```

**Note**, I also tried to to use [`substrate.query_map()`](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#query-a-mapped-storage-function) for [Token.Accounts](https://karura.subscan.io/runtime/Tokens?version=2023#:%7E:text=352%2C%20%22value_id%22%3A%200%20%7D%20%7D-,Accounts,-%7B%20%22origin%22%3A%20%22Map%22%2C%20%22n_map_type) storage function but that requires 1 parameter which I can't discern.

```
result = substrate.query_map(
module='Tokens',
storage_function='Accounts',
page_size=10,
max_results = 100)

**ValueError**: Storage function map requires 1 parameters, 0 given
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to find out which parameters are required for `substrate.query()` & `substrate.query_map()`? I have been digging around in the [library docs](https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/#substrateinterface.SubstrateInterface.query) along with [substrate storage documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/) but I can't figure it out.

**Other Note**: Through trial and error I managed to figure out that `substrate.query()` Tokens.Accounts for a KSM balance of a single Karura account requires two paramaters: `params = ['karura_address',{'Token':'KSM'}]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Ollie!

I suggest you take your question to the very new and very cool dedicated [Substrate StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/). You will get fast an dedicated support there!

Comment: Great idea! doing so now.

Comment: Substrate stack exchange post on this [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-to-determine-which-parameters-are-required-when-using-substrate-query-to-q)